# Copyright of recorded sport events

Tags: copyright, sport

I understand that music concerts are copyrighted and you can't post the music online if you record it with phone or whatever, but how about sport events?
Say I attended a tennis match and recorded some of it or even fully with my camera, can i post it online ? without getting copyright flagged of course.

Comment: Not really a copyright issue, but it may be a condition on your ticket that you may not record video.  So if they see you with a camera out, you might get ejected from the game and/or banned from future games.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe it is a violation of copyright. You are the author of your own video.  After all, you're making the creative choices of what to film, when to zoom in, etc. The fact that someone else is also creating a film has no bearing on that, and of course sports are not scripted, so you can't be violating the copyright of a script (like you would be if you snuck onto a movie set.)

However, you might run afoul of other laws, especially if you try to make a profit. For example, Wisconsin has [this law](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/statutes/statutes/943/III/208):

> 943.208  Recording performance without consent of performance owner.
> (1)  Whoever does any of the following for commercial advantage or private financial gain may be penalized as provided in sub. (2):
>
> (a) Creates a recording of a performance without consent of the performance owner and with intent to sell or rent the recording.
> (b) Advertises, offers for sale or rent, sells, rents or transports a recording of a performance with knowledge that the sounds, images or both from the performance embodied in the recording were recorded without the consent of the performance owner.
> (c) Possesses with intent to advertise, offer for sale or rent, sell, rent or transport a recording of a performance with knowledge that the sounds, images or both from the performance embodied in the recording were recorded without the consent of the performance owner.

I am not sure of the definition of "transport", but it's not unreasonable to think a court would find that uploading a video is "transporting" it, as it's now on a computer in a different location.